# Generate a two dimensional array via LINQ

Tags: linq, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a matrix of doubles, representing a correlation between entities.

Here's how I'm doing it via LINQ

```
double[][] correlationsRaw = (from e in entitiesInOrder
                              select
                                (from f in entitiesInOrder
                                     select correlations.GetCorrelation(e, f)
                                ).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

That works fine.

But what I *want* is a two dimensional array (*double[,]*), not a jagged array.

Obviously, I can write some nested *for* loop to convert one into the other.

But is there some elegant LINQ trick I can use here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way of directly returning a multidimensional array from a Linq query... however you could create a function that takes a jagged array and return a multidimensional array :

```
public T[,] JaggedToMultidimensional<T>(T[][] jaggedArray)
{
    int rows = jaggedArray.Length;
    int cols = jaggedArray.Max(subArray => subArray.Length);
    T[,] array = new T[rows, cols];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        cols = jaggedArray[i].Length;
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = jaggedArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

By the way, it could be an extension method, allowing you to use it in a Linq query...

Comment: @StuartLC or just use `for(int j = 0; j < jaggedArray[i].Length; j++)` for the inner loop. I edited my answer.