# 2d Array from text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text, 2d

I have a text file that looks like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

in a 10 x 10 grid.
using c#
I need to take the text file and turn it into a 2d array of integers so that I can manipulate the integers on an independent level. Please help cant work it out,

Comment: To be helped you should post what you have tried and what problem you have. Just asking people for code without effort is not welcomed on this site

Comment: you need to show what youve done so far - if nothing, then what you intend to do!

Comment: I do aplogise I am new to the site but will bare it in mind for future references

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String input = File.ReadAllText( @"c:\myfile.txt" );

int i = 0, j = 0;
int[,] result = new int[10, 10];
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
{
    j = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        result[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

The indices will be **0-based** so if you want to access **10th** column in **fourth** row:

```
Console.WriteLine(result[3,9]); //40
```

Answer (score 8):

A jagged array?

```
int[][] list = File.ReadAllLines("a.txt")
                   .Select(l => l.Split(' ').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray())
                   .ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

You can use JaggedToMultidimensional [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814063/932418)

```
int[,] list2 = JaggedToMultidimensional(list);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it has to be a 2d array, cant get my head around it

Comment: whats the using directive for it?>

Comment: sorted it now, Thanks for all you help

Comment: What's going on inthis code?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
var result = File.ReadLines(path)
    .SelectMany((l, i) => l.Split()
                           .Select(s => new int[] { i, int.Parse(s) })
                           .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

**Edit**: Although this is a jagged array `int[][]`.