# Saving Text to array

Tags: c#

I have been using this link as an example, but have been having troubles with it:
[2d Array from text file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724781/2d-array-from-text-file-c-sharp)

I have a textfile that contains :

```
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
```

And I'm trying to use the function:

```
static void Training_Pattern_Coords()
{
    String input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Left.txt");

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int[,] result = new int[4, 4];
    foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
    {
        j = 0;
        foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
        {
            result[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
            j++;
        }
        i++;      
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result[1, 3]);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However I keep getting the error message (Input String was not in correct format)  at the line :

```
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
```

I think it has something to do with the spaces within the textfile but I'm not entirely sure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry the text file is a 4x4 array with spaces between them but it has come up as one line in the question:

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The lines are most probably separated by `\r\n` (carriage return / line feed).

Comment: Just tried the same and it works. Your lines are not exactly separated by `\n` rather `\r\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `File.ReadAllText` use `File.ReadLines`.By doing that you won't need to use `Split('\n')`.

```
int[,] result = new int[4, 4];

var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Left.txt")
               .Select(x => x.Split()).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        result[i, j] = int.Parse(lines[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: He should use `ReadLines` over `ReadAllLines`, given that he's only ever `foreach`ing over it, for the sake of the reduced memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as opposed to [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Replace any `\r` (carriage return)

```
input = input.Replace('\r',' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your \r to "\r\n"

Try this:

```
foreach (var row in input.Split("\r\n"))
```