# Array covering a map of rows and columns

Tags: arrays, integer, parseint

public char[][] mapData; 
Example of it: mapData[k][j] is the character at row k and column j of the map file, which is read with scanner. Here "k" goes from 0 to rows-1, and "j" from 0 to columns-1.

Im stuck with this at the moment, and not sure how to proceed from this?

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int cols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int G = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int Z = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    char[][] mapData;
    Position[] zombies;
    br.close();
```

How do i create an array of the rows and how do i implement it into a 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to read a two-dimensional array from the text file you could  use one of these solutions: [2d Array from text file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724781/2d-array-from-text-file-c-sharp)

Of cause you could add some validation (row and col count).