# Convert IEnumerable to multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a pretty way I can change my previous code:

```
char[][] board = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat('-', 7).ToArray(), 7).ToArray();
```

so that it uses multidimensional arrays instead?

E.g.

```
char[,] = ...
```

the array should represent this kind of data structure:

```
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
-------
```

Comment: Why do you think the latter is better than the former?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list of arrays into a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774901/how-to-convert-list-of-arrays-into-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Here is another one http://stackoverflow.com/a/1814063/5233410

Comment: @KirkWoll the former isn't working, when I try to assign `board[5][2] = '*'` it seems to assign in every row, rather than just the 6th.

Comment: @minseong, no it _absolutely_ does not work that way.

Comment: @KirkWoll what? That is how I have always assigned to 2d arrays (well, "jagged" arrays) in every other language I have used

Comment: @minseong, I have no idea what you are talking about.  `x[a][b] = y` will only ever assign a single element in every language I've ever seen.

Comment: @KirkWoll which is what I want, but that isn't happening

Comment: @minseong, please provide an MCVE that illustrates the behavior you describe.  As I can guarantee what you are describing is not what happens in C#.

Comment: @KirkWoll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644966/how-to-assign-to-a-jagged-array

Comment: @KirkWoll what is an MCVE

Comment: It's on the help pages: [mcve]

Comment: Please provide a console application with a `Main` method that demonstrates the behavior you describe.  I looked at the question you just linked to and that's not going to work -- too much hand waving.

Comment: @KirkWoll I have an app that does ihis

Comment: @KirkWoll I am about to add it to the other question

Comment: Yes, do whatever you can to provide a short program that demonstrates the problem and I guarantee you will get an exponentially more useful response.

Comment: @minseong and above all, make sure your example actually *compiles*! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
            char[,] board = new char[7,7];

            for(int i =0; i< 7; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                {
                    board[i,k] = '-';
                }
            }
```

Are you looking for this?

Comment: Yes, but IMO that is really ugly.

Comment: Well this is the standard way of initialising a 2d array:)

Comment: may be you can put this in an initialiser method and then call it with a parameter